# Error in displaying values from database on table

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uitableview

I am doing a Birthday remainder Application by using SQLITE database.I am saving values in database . I displayed first name On the table view so that if i click that i can see that person entire details. For example i saved some 5 person details in database.

When i close that application and run again i am not able to display that saved values in the table view.But i am getting that saved values only i am not able to display that first name which i saw previously when i am closing that application.
When i run the application for the first time i am not able to go to this method (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) in tale view. When i add details then its going to this (`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) method.

Can any one help me in this. Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code, maybe we can help out

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your data source (database) and return the proper values for

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

once you return these values properly based on your datasource then cellForRowAtIndexpath will get called.

Of course you should ensure that your viewcontroller is properly designated as the tableview's delegate and datasource.

Comment: I checked all this things before and still i dint got so i posted this post.what u mentioned above i check that things before only.

Comment: Did you see the calls to numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection?   Did you verify their return values?  Sometimes people "check" but they don't check correctly.   If nothing's working you can try removing pieces of your code until you reach all the way back to a bare application with hardcoded values for # sections # rows, printing a simple cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath.   I believe you've probably overlooked something fundamental, but it's hard to say for sure without code.